# howto use tokens as "views filter criteria"

Tags: views, tokens

I want make a photo gallery with Drupal and i want show photos uploaded by user in user's page.
I tried add token `[node:author:uid]` to `Content: Author uid` as filter criteria, but that shows an error:

```
Unable to find user: [node:author:uid]
```

how to add a token to views filter criteria?
thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried using contextual filters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a contextual filter - Content: Author uid and make it like below. I think this is what you need.

[image]

Comment: thnaks :) that worked :)